# Transfer data from jsp to servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I trie to send data from a jsp form to a servlet, but im not able to read the data sended via POST method in the servlet.
this is the servlet code

```
public class TUhServlet extends HttpServlet {
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {



        String s= req.getParameter("post_text");
        System.out.println(s);
        resp.sendRedirect("/tuh.jsp");
    }
}
```

This is the form in tuh.jsp

```
<form class="post_form" action="./" 
              method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            0"/><br/>
            Message : <input name="post_text" type="text" size="30" maxlength="30"/>
            <p><input type="submit" value="Post!"/></p>
            <input type="hidden" name="type" value="post"/>
        </form>
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>TUh</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>tuh.TUhServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>TUh</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/tuh</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>tuh.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: your <sevlet-class> value (tuh.TUBlrServlet) doesn't match your servlet name (TUhServlet), your action attribute in form declaration seems wrong.

Comment: I just edit it, I changed the name before I post the message

Comment: In your action form attribute use "tuh" instead of "./"

Answer (score 3):

For `<input type="text">` you have to set the name of the component as shown in [StackOverflow Servlets wiki example](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info):

```html
<input id="post_text" name="post_text" type="text" size="30" maxlength="30"/>
```

Do the same for all your components as well like the `hidden` field.

You have other problems with the form you posted in your code:

- In a simple form, you must not have an `enctype="multipart/form-data"` at least that you're handling file uploads (that's not shown in the example). If the code is just to send a text data from client to server, remove this.
- The `action` attribute in your `<form>` doesn't send the info to the right URL mapping of the servlet. You should change it to `/thu`.

In the end, your `<form>` should look like

```
<form class="post_form" action="thu" method="post">
    <!-- contents... -->
</form>
```

In case you're handling a file upload but didn't posted all the JSP code here, then you should look for another approach to extract the data send in the request explained here: [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2422468/1065197)

Comment: I think name attribute is required, not ID

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the `name` attribute for all the input elements that you want to access on servlet:

```
<input name="post_text" type="text" size="30" maxlength="30"/>
```

Now as @Luiggi mentioned, but I think `ID` attribute is not required, `name` attribute is required.

Answer (score 0):

I think you not need `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and check your mapping in web.xml file. It should need to change the url as @Luiggi Mendoza mentioned. we can't send vlaues using `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. In my project I have tried that.But in your problem can be solve with changing those codes.....